# Teamviewer: Monitor screen activity of subordinates PCs without getting noticed

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer, surveillance

I have 7 subordinates who work in our Office Branches, who use our official PC but sometimes they watch movies or some adult stuff during office hours which is not permitted by Rule. I installed teamviewer to those PCs as well as mine (via high speed internet) but when I get connected, firstly, they can notice while I'm connected as there are some activity appears in their PC, secondly while I move my mouse, their mouse pointer also moves so they become alert. But employee with serious offense like watching adult film, they become used to that symptom, become  alert and promptly hide content easily. I tried freezing their mouse movement or blanking screen, that time they think PC has hung so, they restart the PC. So that's not useful most of the time, as monitoring their activity.

What I need is I connect to their PC they can not detect that, and I don't need to control their PC, just to see what they are doing. If any offense, I can take a snapshot and report to my superior. If it's possible with Teamviewer then How, Please tell me or if it's not possible with Teamviewer, which tool can help me to do such just that information shall be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1291395/are-there-anyway-to-track-people-s-browser-history-through-my-router-if-they-re/1291396#1291396 something like this may be a better solution, it's transparent to the users.

Comment: I believe tightvnc would also work. There are settings to view only, then the mouse scenario doesn't come into play. And the last version I used did not notify the user via taskbar.

Comment: +1 for tightvnc, this is a perfect use-case for it.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I don't understand whatever is in the link you have mentioned, with the answer or with your comment there. (maybe I have no knowledge about it what you were discussing. 
Tightvnc I found it useful but Problem is the Internet connection via Telecom in India always assigns a newer IP(dynamic IP), so when I set it with a current IP for the remote PC, how can I continuously get newer IP when the are connected? This facility I get with teamviewer is with making an account for each PC and adding those to mine. Another Problem is It's updates the screen slowly comparing Teamviewer.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvote my question. Maybe the one whose's answer was down-voted by others and eliminated. Look brother, I did not downvote or elliminate your answer. I don't ask for any reputation here, I really need help but downvoting may seem to other user this question may not be useful for them.

Comment: @atok you are probably being downvoted because this technically falls under a corporate / Enterprise question. It really isn't a question for this forum.

Comment: Oh! sorry! I did not know that, then in which forum I should have asked? I do not find any forum named corporate or Enterprise in stack exchange.

Comment: @atok the link I mentioned, if you follow the instructions. Will allow you to record all websites viewed by all employees, regardless of them trying to hide history etc. It would give you lists of everything that was accessed through each employees browser with date/time.

Comment: @atok.. I believe serverfault entertains Corporate/Enterprise questions. Read the rules in the help center before you post.

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer is unsuitable for this kind of usage.
You need specialized software for that, which unfortunately is commercial,
although a trial is usually available.

Here are a couple of well-known such products :

- [ActivTrak](https://activtrak.com/)
- [Activity Monitor](https://www.softactivity.com/activity-monitor/)

I have no experience with these products and cannot vouch for any of them.
ActivTrak seems like the most sophisticated :

[image]

Comment: By the way, if you're using teamviewer for commercial reasons, you are supposed to buy a commercial licence anyway, so the fact that these alternatives are commercial shouldn't make a difference (if OP is following the licence's policies)

Comment: Well Sounds cool. but do they have any android client? not found in their site. I need it because often I'm in the field.

Comment: Quite a lot of these products too, you just have to search and compare. For example [Net Monitor for Employees](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.networklookout&hl=en).

Comment: @harrymc thanks, let me try them and come back. So far I tried with those two Those are more technical but but not like teamviewer which is sharing live screen cast.

Comment: If you are looking for the perfect product, I cannot help with that - product recommendation is not allowed on this site. I have shown you that there are heaps of products available, even by just querying google for "employee monitoring windows android". The search and the choice are yours to do.

Comment: If you find the perfect product, such as ActivTrak, and it's not available for android, you can use Teamviewer or its like between your own computer and tablet.